# Creating my own PaperClip GEM? for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, paperclip

based on the needs of my app, I need to make a modification to paperclip, it's only one line but it makes all the difference for my apps needs.

In my Rails 3 GEM FILE I have the following:

```
gem 'paperclip', '2.3.5'
```

With github, how does one go about making there own paperclip GEM? So I can use it on Heroku?

Something like

```
gem 'paperclip', '2.3.5' -> my version?
```

Would love to hear how this is done. How this is maintained as paperclip is updated. and how I use this locally and on Heroku.

Thanks

Comment: BTW: You should consider KandadaBoggu's suggestion to use monkey patching instead of making your own fork. Generally you want to fork if you think that whatever you're changing will benefit others (like fixing a bug.) However, if you just want to tweak the code for your specific app, then monkey patching might be more straight forward. Basically, you can create an initializer file where you open up the gem class that you want to modify and make the code changes that you want. (See http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/18 for an example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the github page on 'Forking'. http://help.github.com/forking/

Answer (score 1):

You must fork the repo on github. Then, instead of passing a version in the Gemfile, pass the following:
    gem 'paperclip', :git=>'git://github.com/username/repo.git'

Comment: know of any good tutorials showing the start to finish? Also had a few other related questions.. like keeping updated.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you creating a gem for this? You can monkey patch the gem. This will allow you to use the standard version. What is the change you need? What is the link to your gem, may be there is an easier solution.